# What means the term "sopheric" ("sopherisch" - this question cites a short german sentence)

Tags: words, kohelet

Reading Heinrich Graetz's 1871 study on "Kohelet" again I run on the term "sopherisch", even in connection with "postexilic-sopheric".  Never heard this word before; google, wikipedia are of not much help here: what does it mean?

> (...) Das Judentum, das altbiblische, wie das nachexilisch-sopherische,
> hat die Unsterblichkeitslehre keineswegs als Glaubensartikel  aufgestellt.
>
> Das durch die sopherische Leitung neu aufgebaute Judenthum
> kennt nur die Auferstehung der Leiber (...)

(H. Graetz, "Kohelet oder der Salomonische Prediger", Einleitung, S.29)

---

*... hopefully my tags are meaningful...*

Comment: I suppose he refers to [Ezra the scribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezra) and his successors after the Babylonian exile.

Comment: *Never heard this word before; Google, Wikipedia are of not much help here: what does it mean?* - By clicking the very first result of a simple [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=sopheric), providing a link to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sopheric), the word's meaning was soon [revealed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sopherim) to mean [scribal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scribe). Wikipedia also provides [meaningful results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofer).

Comment: @Lucian - thanks; I seem to have googled for the german notation (not expecting, that I would easily understand a complicated concept in english) A german equivalent (perhaps) to the Mirriam-Webster (and familiar to me) is the "Brockhaus", but it didn't show up any entry. Google gave a handful of german texts for me, but where the word was in contexts (again in Graetz but also elsewhere) but not in explanation. So thanks again for your hints! For me the thing can be closed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he may mean - the production of a sofer.

See https://www.jstor.org/stable/23113406?seq=1

Wenn das Gesetz ihrer Ansicht nach nur „sopherisch" war und sie es un~ erträglich und unausführbar fanden, warum suchten sie dann einen Ausweg.

The inverted commas imply that the person quoting thought it was a made-up word.

Comment: you mean דברי סורפים?

Comment: Just found the same word in another book of Graetz on the history. Perhaps even he himself has constructed that word... Thanks for the hint, looks very likely!

Comment: (+1 & "accepted") - thanks for the impulse which helped me to search in a fruitful direction

Answer (score 0):

***Update*** : I found a more explanative region in Graetz's "Geschichte der Juden", ["Zweiter Zeitraum, erste Epoche, Kapitel 5, das Sopherische Zeitalter"](http://www.zeno.org/Geschichte/M/Graetz,+Heinrich/Geschichte+der+Juden/%5BZweiter+Zeitraum%5D/%5BErste+Epoche.%5D+Die+Wiedergeburt+im+Elend/5.+Kapitel.+Das+sopherische+Zeitalter)

> (...) Die geistigen Führer des Volkes haben der künftigen Generation eindringlich empfohlen: »Stellet nur recht viele Jünger auf,« und was sie als so wichtig empfohlen haben, haben sie ohne Zweifel selbst mit vielem Eifer betätigt. Eine solche höhere Schule (Bet-Waad) wurde gewiß in Jerusalem eingerichtet, obwohl die Namen der Leiter derselben unbekannt geblieben sind, sowie überhaupt der Männer, welche still-geschäftig den festen Unterbau zur Erhaltung und zum Fortbestand des Judentums gefügt haben. Die unbeschränkte Lehrfreiheit und der Eifer, Kenntnis der Gesetze zu verbreiten, haben mit der Zeit die Zahl der Jünger vermehrt.
> ***Die Lehrer wurden »Schriftkundige« (Sopherim)*** oder »Weise«, die Jünger »Weisenschüler« (Talmide Chachamim) genannt. *Die Tätigkeit der Weisen oder Schriftkundigen war doppelter Art, nach der einen Seite, die Gesetze der Thora auszulegen, und nach der anderen, sie für das Leben der einzelnen und der Gesamtheit anwendbar zu machen.* Da nämlich manche Vorschriften des Gesetzes nicht deutlich genug abgefaßt sind und Dunkelheiten enthalten, namentlich bezüglich des Umfanges ihrer Verbindlichkeit, ob für sämtliche Volksklassen oder lediglich für einzelne, ob für beide Geschlechter oder lediglich für eins derselben, so war es Sache der Schriftkundigen, solche Vorschriften, Gebote und Verbote zu deuten, zu beschränken oder zu verallgemeinern, die Zeit der Verpflichtung zu bestimmen und überhaupt sie zu ergänzen. Diese ergänzende Schriftauslegung wurde Deutung (Midrasch)29 genannt, die nicht willkürlich sein durfte, sondern wohl von gewissen, wenn auch dunklen Auslegungsregeln bedingt war. (...)

For my needs, this explains fully and with context, the term "Sopherism" as a (historically) new way to teach the community in and after the babylonian detention (?english word?) ... that has been a funny snakelike track, I must say... Happy to be successful with the enquiry.

english by google translate:

> (...) The spiritual leaders of the people have urgently recommended to the
> future generation: "Make up only a great number of disciples," and
> what they have recommended as so important, they have undoubtedly
> carried out themselves with great zeal. Such a higher school
> (Bet-Waad) was certainly established in Jerusalem, although the names
> of the heads of the same have remained unknown, as well as of the men
> in general who quietly and industriously laid the solid foundation for
> the preservation and continued existence of Judaism. ***The
> unrestricted freedom of teaching and the zeal to spread knowledge of
> the law have increased the number of disciples over time. The teachers
> were called "writers" (Sopherim) or "wise men", the disciples
> "wisemen" (Talmide Chachamim).*** The activity of the wise or
> literate was twofold: on the one hand, to interpret the laws of the
> Torah, and on the other, to make them applicable to the life of the
> individual and the community. Since some of the provisions of the law
> are not drafted clearly enough and contain obscurities, namely with
> regard to the extent of their binding force, whether for all classes
> of the people or only for some, whether for both sexes or only for one
> of them, it was up to the literate to issue such provisions To
> interpret, limit or generalize commandments and prohibitions, to
> determine the time of the obligation and to supplement it in general.
> This supplementary interpretation of Scripture was called
> interpretation (midrash), which was not allowed to be arbitrary, but
> was probably conditioned by certain, albeit dark, rules of
> interpretation (...).

---

(My own first, original, answer)

I've found a more explanative piece in Graetz' "Geschichte der Juden", "Erster Zeitraum, zweite Epoche, Noten" auf [zeno.org](http://www.zeno.org/Geschichte/M/Graetz,+Heinrich/Geschichte+der+Juden/Erster+Zeitraum/Zweite+Epoche.+Die+Bl%C3%BCtezeit/Noten/16.+Die+Bedeutung+der+%C3%84mter+Sopher+und+Maskhhir):

> **16. Die Bedeutung der Ämter Sopher und Maskhhir.**

> [418] Die Methode, gleichklingende hebräische Wörter von grundverschiedener Bedeutung unter einen Hut zu bringen, eine gleichklingende arabische oder aramäische Wurzel per fas et nefas zur Vergleichung heranzuziehen und daraus die Grundbedeutung abzuleiten, hat zu vielen Irrtümern geführt. Es ist hier der Ort nicht, nachzuweisen, wie ein Teil der etymologischen Operationen in der hebräischen Lexikographie auf Verkennung beruht, und daß die Entfaltung der Bedeutung der Wörter nicht genetisch verfolgt wurde. Hier soll nur die Ableitung und Bedeutung von רפס und ריפזמ entwickelt werden, mit welchen an dem israelitischen Hofe von David an Beamte benannt werden.

> Bei רפס [sofer] wird in den Etymologicis vorausgeschickt, daß der Name רפס im Aramäischen, Neuhebräischen und allenfalls auch im Arabischen abschaben und scheren bedeutet, רפס ein »Scherer« und םירפסמ »Schere«, ferner bedeutet רפס Meeresküste und Grenze. Aber damit ist nichts anzufangen, und es reicht nicht aus, das hebräische Verbum רפס [safar] »zählen« und רפס [siper] »erzählen« zu erklären. Da wird eine unbegründete Urbedeutung »eingraben, einschneiden« aufgestellt und die arabische Analogie herbeigezogen, daß ausnahmsweise רפס auch »ein Buch schreiben« bedeute. Damit ist der etymologische Ausbau fertig. Übersehen wird, daß die Wurzel רפס im Arabischen sehr viele und die allerverschiedensten Bedeutungen involviert, und daß es meistens »eine Reise machen« und »dem Kamel einen Maulkorb anlegen« bedeutet. Da im Arabischen רפס auch ein großes Buch bedeutet, und zwar ganz besonders den Pentateuch, so hätten die Etymologen daran erkennen sollen, daß diese seltenere Bedeutung des Substantivums (und auch des Verbums רפס »ein Buch schreiben«) erst durch judäischen Einfluß in das Arabische eingedrungen sein kann.

> Geht man davon aus, daß רפס im Hebräischen ursprünglich »Schreiber« und als Hofamt »Kanzler« bedeute, so wird damit ein kulturhistorisches Moment vorausgesetzt, das erst nachgewiesen werden muß, nämlich, daß an den israelitischen Höfen von David an die Tagesbegebenheiten aufgeschrieben und aufgezeichnet worden seien. Sieht man aber von den schillernden Analogien ab und sucht die Bedeutung auf, welche das Wort im Hebräischen vorherrschend hat, so kommt man zu einem anderen Resultat. Zugegeben wird wohl werden, daß die Partizipialform רפס [sofer] jüngeren Ursprungs ist als die Verbalformen.

> [418] Nun bedeutet, wie schon gesagt, רפס im Hebräischen nichts anderes als »zählen« und im Piel »er zählen«, d.h. die Vorgänge der Reihe nach »aufzählen«, z.B. םתוא תואצמה לכ תא ול ורפסיו (Josua 2, 23); עשילא השע רשא תולדגה לכ תא יל אנ הרפס (II. Könige 8, 4). Es involviert auch die Bedeutung: »eine wohlgesetzte Erzählung von dem Werte einer Person geben«, gewissermaßen das Epos eines Lebenden auseinandersetzen, daher loben, rühmen, preisen; davon רפס דובכ, ferner תולהת רפס, auch םישעמ und תואלפנ. In רפס [sofer] kann also nur die Bedeutung »Zähler« liegen, einer, welcher zählt. Gezählt wurde die Mannschaft, welche zum Kriege ausgehoben wurde, 1000 aus einem Stamm oder 1000 aus einer größeren und 100 aus einer kleineren Stadt (Amos 5, 3). רפס hat ungefähr die Bedeutung wie das griechische καταλέγειν στρατιώτας, Soldaten ausheben, weil die ausgehobenen Krieger in eine Liste eingetragen wurden. Derjenige, welcher dieses Geschäft verrichtete, hieß רפס [sofer], gleich καταλογεύς, der eine Liste anlegt. So wie der καταλογεύς eine Liste der Gezählten, κατάλογος, anfertigte, ebenso der רפס [sofer] ein רפס [sefer], eine »Liste«. – רפס30 ist also ursprünglich nichts anderes als eine Zählungsliste, eine lange Rolle Papyrus, worin die Ausgehobenen eingezeichnet waren. Der רפס hatte also nur ein militärisches Amt, was auch deutlich hervorgeht aus Jeremia 52, 25; II. Könige 25, 19, םע תא אבצמה אבצה רש רפסה ץראה. Er führte einen Stab zur Züchtigung bei sich רפס טבשב םיכשמ (Richter 5, 14). Der ךלמה רפס oder ךלמל war also nur ein militärischer Beamter.

***I'll take this sentence as the -for me- relevant characterization:***

> ***Erst später wurde רפס der Schreiber überhaupt*** genannt, weil das Amt desselben es mit sich brachte, zu schreiben, und רפס [sefer] erhielt die Bedeutung »Rolle«. תותירכ רפס und הנקמה רפס vgl. auch Numeri 5, 23.

*This surely is not enough to really understand the expression* "nachexilisch-sopheristisch" *, but it gives a direction for the understanding. Perhaps there will exist more information on this*

> Als רפס die Bedeutung eines größeren Volumens erhielt, gebrauchte man für eine kleine Rolle den Ausdruck רפס תלגמ, und erst als רפס noch dazu die Bedeutung »Buch«, und zwar הרותה רפס »Gesetzbuch«, erhalten hat, war der רפס, der Buchkundige, identisch mit ןיבמ. Man muß also namentlich bei der Bedeutung des Wortes רפס die vorexilische und die nachexilische Zeit auseinanderhalten. David war der erste, welcher das Sopheramt eingeführt hat, da er infolge der häufigen Kriege die Übersicht über die Disponibilität der Truppen haben mußte. Der erste, der dieses Amt bekleidete, war הירש oder אשיש (אוש). Seine Söhne erbten dieses Amt unter Salomo (I. Könige 4, 3). Unter Jojakim gab es sogar zwei Zählmeister (Jeremia 36, 10-12). Der letzte dieses Amtes wird wohl Jonathan unter Zedekia gewesen sein (das. 37, 15 f.).

---

as requested a translation to english. Please bear with me, I'm not a native english speaker and it would be really difficult (and likely have many errors) to translate this philosophical/religious/historial text into english. So I'll give you a google-translation, which I think should give at least an idea what Graetz has been thinking about:

> 16. The importance of the offices of Sopher and Maskhhir.
>
>     [418] The method of combining Hebrew words with the same sounding of fundamentally different meanings, using an Arabic or Aramaic root
>     with the same sounding per fas et nefas for comparison and deriving
>     the basic meaning from this, has led to many errors. It is not the
>     place here to show how some of the etymological operations in Hebrew
>     lexicography are based on misunderstanding, and that the development
>     of the meaning of the words has not been genetically traced. Here only
>     the derivation and meaning of רפס and רי, are to be developed, with
>     which officials at the Israelite court of David are named.
>
>     In the case of רפס [sofer], the Etymologicis states that the name רפס means scrape and shear in Aramaic, New Hebrew and possibly also in
>     Arabic, רפס means “shearers” and םירפסמ means “scissors”, furthermore
>     רפס means seashore and border. But there is nothing to be done with
>     that, and it is not enough to explain the Hebrew verb רפס [safar]
>     "count" and רפס [siper] "tell". An unfounded original meaning "dig in,
>     cut in" is established and the Arabic analogy is used that, as an
>     exception, רפס also means "to write a book". The etymological
>     expansion is now complete. What is overlooked is that the root רפס in
>     Arabic has a great many and very different meanings and that it mostly
>     means "to go on a journey" and "to muzzle the camel". Since רפס also
>     means a large book in Arabic, and in particular the Pentateuch, the
>     etymologists should have recognized that this rarer meaning of the
>     noun (and also of the verb רפס "to write a book") only came through
>     Judean influence in Arabic may have penetrated.
>
>     Assuming that רפס in Hebrew originally meant "scribe" and as court office "chancellor", then a cultural-historical element is assumed
>     that must first be proven, namely that the events of the day were
>     written down and recorded by David at the Israelite courts have been.
>     But if one disregards the dazzling analogies and looks for the meaning
>     which the word has predominantly in Hebrew, one arrives at a different
>     result. It will probably be admitted that the participle form רפס
>     [sofer] is of more recent origin than the verbal forms.
>
>     [418] Now, as already said, רפס in Hebrew means nothing more than "count" and in Piel "he count", i.e. "enumerate" the events one after
>     the other, e.g. םתוא תואצמה לכ תא ול ורפסיו (Joshua 2:23); עשילא השע
>     רשא תולדגה לכ תא יל אנ הרפס (II Kings 8: 4). It also involves the
>     meaning: "to give a well-established narrative of the values ​​of a
>     person", in a sense to deal with the epic of a living person, hence to
>     praise, praise, praise; of which רפס דובכ, also תולהת רפס, also םישעמ
>     and תואלפנ. In רפס [sofer] there can only be the meaning "counter",
>     one that counts. The number of crews that was drafted for war was 1000
>     from a tribe or 1000 from a larger and 100 from a smaller town (Amos
>     5, 3). רפס has roughly the same meaning as the Greek καταλέγειν
>     στρατιώτας, to raise soldiers because the excavated warriors were
>     entered in a list. The one who did this business was called רפס
>     [sofer], like καταλογεύς, who made a list. Just as the καταλογεύς made
>     a list of the counted, κατάλογος, just as the רפס [sofer] a רפס
>     [sefer], a "list". - So רפס 30 is originally nothing more than a list
>     of counts, a long roll of papyrus in which the excavated were marked.
>     The רפס thus only had a military office, which is also clearly evident
>     from Jeremiah 52:25; II. Kings 25:19, םע תא אבצמה אבצה רש רפסה ץראה.
>     He carried a stick with him for chastisement רפס טבשב םיכשמ (Judges
>     5:14). So the ךלמה רפס or ךלמל was just a military official.

***Now my selected piece:***

> *** Only later was רפס the scribe even called ***, because the office of the same involved writing, and רפס [sefer] was given the meaning "role". תותירכ רפס and הנקמה רפס cf. also Numbers 5, 23.

> When רפס got the meaning of a larger volume, the expression רפס תלגמ was used for a small role, and only when רפס received the meaning "book", namely הרותה רפס "code of law", was רפס, the literary expert , identical to ןיבמ. One must therefore keep a distinction between the pre-exilic and the post-exilic period when referring to the meaning of the word רפס. David was the first to introduce the Sopher Office, as the frequent wars meant that he had to have an overview of the availability of the troops. The first to hold this office was הירש or אשיש (אוש). His sons inherited this office under Solomon (I Kings 4: 3). Under Jehoiakim there were even two counters (Jeremiah 36, 10-12). The last of this office will probably have been Jonathan under Zedekiah (das. 37, 15 f.).

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some translation for the non-German speakers please?

Comment: @Dov - hope it's fine for you to see the google-translate. To try to translate such a text would be too much for me, at best I meanwhile can relatively well write mathematical texts of my hobby explorations, and short conversations. But my doughter, who had always the highest marks in school in english (and lives now in England), often cries out loud when she reads my elaborates... ;)